# brute force search optimisation

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, brute-force

I have an function that is engineered as follows:

```
int brutesearch(startNumber,endNumber);
```

this function returns the correct number if one matches my criteria by performing a linear search, or null if it's not found in the searched numbers.

Say that:

- I want to search all 6 digits numbers to find one that does something I want
- I can run the brutesearch() function multithreaded
- I have a laptop with 4 cores

My question is the following:

What is my best bet for optimising this search? Dividing the number space in 4 segments and running 4 instances of the function one on each core? Or dividing for example in 10 segments and running them all together, or dividing in 12 segments and running them in batches of 4 using a queue?

Any ideas?

Comment: The computational complexity of your problem is unaffected by the way you choose to portion work out to threads/processes/cores.  This means that the choice between the options you outline can only be sensibly made empirically -- so do some experiments and come to a conclusion.  My guess would be 4 portions, 1 to each core, ensuring that you have a mechanism in place to stop all the portions when one is successful.

Comment: I think you you're asking the wrong question.  You shouldn't be asking "how can I leverage my laptop's 4 cores?"; you should be asking "is my linear search algorithm the correct approach?".  Depending on what you mean by "find one that does something I want", you may be able to use a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing nothing about your search criteria (there may be other considerations created by the memory subsystem), the tradeoff here is between the cost of having some processors do more work than others (e.g., because the search predicate is faster on some values than others, or because other threads were scheduled) and the cost of coordinating the work. A strategy that's worked well for me is to have a work queue from which threads grab a constant/#threads fraction of the remaining tasks each time, but with only four processors, it's pretty hard to go wrong, though the really big running-time wins are in algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer. You need to give more information.

If your each comparison is completely independent of the others, and there are no opportunities for saving computation in a global resource, there is say no global hash tables involved, and your operations are all done in a single stage,

then your best bet is to just divide your problem space into the number of cores you have available, in this case 4 and send 1/4 of the data to each core.

For example if you had 10 million unique numbers that you wanted to test for primality. Or if you had 10 million passwords your were trying to hash to find a match, then just divide by 4.

If you have a real world problem, then you need to know a lot more about the underlying operations to get a good solution. For example if a global resource is involved, then you won't get any improvement from parallelism unless you isolate the operations on the global resource somehow.